# ¿Cómo remplazar una palabra en específico con php?

Tags: php, preg-match

¿Cómo podria remplazar una palabra en específico con php?

Aquí tengo un código de ejemplo:

```
$text = "https://justblab.com/arrow arrow";
if ($b = preg_match("/\barrow\b/i",  $text)) {
    preg_replace('/\barrow\b/i', '%arrow%',  $text); 
    echo $b;
} else {
    echo "No se encontró ninguna coincidencia.";
}
```

Lo que quiero es poder reemplazar la palabra **"arrow"** pero que no remplaze la palabra **"arrow"** del link.

Comment: ¡Bienvenido a [es.so]!  Léete el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento del sitio. Acabo de dejarte una respuesta a tu pregunta, ya nos dirás si te sirve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actualización:

```
$text = "https://justblab.com/arrow arrow arrow/arrow/arrow";
$troceado = explode(" ", $text);
$patron = "/arrow/";
$reemplazo = '';

foreach ($troceado as $trozo) {
    if (!filter_var($trozo, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)) {
        if (preg_match($patron, $trozo)) {
            $trozo = preg_replace($patron, $reemplazo, $trozo);
        }
    }
    $trozos_filtrados[] = $trozo;
}
echo implode(" ", $trozos_filtrados);
```

Prueba y me cuentas.

---

**ANTERIOR RESPUESTA** (no es lo que queria)

Prueba con esto:

```
<?php
$text = "https://justblab.com/arrow arrow";
$patron = "/[[:space:]]arrow/";
$reemplazo = '';
if (preg_match($patron, $text)) {
    $b = preg_replace($patron, $reemplazo, $text);
    echo $b;
} else {
    echo "No se encontró ninguna coincidencia.";
}
```

**Cambios realizados**:

- Para una mejor comodidad y clarificación del código, se han agregado dos variables nuevas, correspondientes al patrón y a la cadena de reemplazo:

```
$patron = "/[[:space:]]arrow/";
$reemplazo = '';
```

donde el patrón lo definimos con un espacio `[[:space:]]` delante de la palabra a buscar para distingirlo del otro `arrow` que pertenece a la url.  La cadena de reemplazo está vacia, porque lo que queremos hacer es sustituir el patrón eliminándolo de la cadena en este caso.

- Se ha cambiado el condicional, de esto:

```
if ($b = preg_match($patron, $text)) {
```

a esto:

```
if (preg_match($patron, $text)) {
```

porque en el primer caso no servía de nada asignarlo a una variable. [preg_match()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.preg-match.php) devuelve `1` o `0` o `false`, lo cual ya es interpretable por el condicional en sí, sin tener que asignarlo a nada.

- Dentro del condicional hemos asignado el resultado del [preg_replace()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.preg-replace.php) a una variable, pues en la pregunta no se asignaba a nada, ni tampoco se imprimia nada, es decir, quizás se ejecutaba el preg_replace correctamente pero no se usaba después para nada al no asignarse ni imprimirse.

```
$b = preg_replace($patron, $reemplazo, $text);
```

- Hemos dejado el:

```
echo $b;
```

porque ahora si que se corresponde con el resultado del preg_replace().

El resultado de estas instrucciones nos arroja:

```
https://justblab.com/arrow
```

que es lo que se pedia en la pregunta.

Comment: muy buena explicacion amigo, gracias por tu comentario, pero lo q necesito saber es de que manera se puede remplazar cualquier palabra que aparesca en el texto pero que no remplaze la del link, por ejemplo si uso este texto de ejemplo "arrow https://arrow.com/arrow arrow arrow" , por ejemplo alguna funcion que detecte que hay un link en el texto y que siendo este un link no se tome en cuenta para el remplazo

Comment: He actualizado mi respuesta, prueba y me cuentas.